# Get next date from day-month

Tags: c#, .net, date

I have one start date and I have next financial year end date's day and month. So based on this data how to get full financial year end date?

ie.

```
start date = 23rd January,2019
financial year end date's day = 31
financial year end date's month = 3

And I want full date as below :
financial year end date = 31st March,2019
```

Help me to how to get this date.

Comment: `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(Date.Now.AddYears(1).Year,financial year end date's month,financial year end date's day)`

Comment: I have updated my question. How to do it with that?

Comment: Do you have these strings as input ? You're going to have a bad time .. Maybe [Humanizr](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) has something on that but I doubt it. Deal with `DateTime` structure instead

Comment: Same code, `Date.Now.AddYears(1).Year` takes todays date, adds a year and gives you the int for the year of the new calculated date. If you still have day and month in the same variables it should work.

Comment: @iDipa, is your financial year end date is correct? please check it is not next year financial end date if start Date is = 23rd Nov 2019

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar he edited his code, it used to be `23rd November,2018`. I think he wants a way to calculate next years financial year end date every year. It's not very clear, tho.

Comment: Yes, I want next financial year end date from day and month

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @iDipa does the day and month change or are the same every year?

Comment: Same every year

Comment: We are missing some details. Should it be just for this thing or should it be automatically? What are the steps for a financial year? Is it always the 31 of March? Do you need it just for 2019? What should be the output? A normal string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, to allow for a variable start date:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2019,1,23);
DateTime financialYear = new DateTime(startDate.Year, 3,31);
if (startDate > financialYear)
{
    financialYear = financialYear.AddYears(1);
}
```

And then format `financialYear` to the required format

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2019,1,23); //23rd January,2019
var financialYearEndDay = 31;
var financialYearEndMonth = 3;
DateTime financialYear = new 
DateTime(date.Year,financialYearEndMonth,financialYearEndDay);
if (startDate > financialYear)
{
    financialYear = financialYear.AddYears(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you just need a new `DateTime` object that takes the year from `startDate`, but has fixed day and month? Then assuming that you have `startDate` as a `DateTime` object already you just do:

```
new DateTime(startDate.Year, financialYearEndMonth, financialYearEndDay)
```